# Redis get and set decorator

Tags: python, caching, redis, decorator

Currently working on python and redis. I have Flask as my framework and working on Blueprints.

Looking into implementing cache with redis for my APIs, I have tried **Flask-Cache** and **redis-simple-cache**.
Downside are [Flask-Cache](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/) saves the function even when you change the parameter of the function. It only saves it once per function.
As per [redis-simple-cache](https://github.com/vivekn/redis-simple-cache), it save its keys as `SimpleCache-<key name>` which not advisable on my end.

So my question is, how can you create a decorator which save and retrieve or check if there is a key existing for the specific key.
I know a save decorator is possible. But is a retrieve or check decorator possible?? Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to not have read the [Flask-Cache documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/) very closely. Caching does *not* ignore parameters and the cache key is customisable. The decorators the project supplies already give you the functionality you seek.

From the [*Caching View Functions* section](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/#caching-view-functions):

> This decorator will use `request.path` by default for the `cache_key`.

So the *default* cache key is `request.path`, but you can specify a different key. Since Flask *view* functions get their arguments from path elements, the default `request.path` makes a great key.

From the [`@cached()` decorator documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/#flask.ext.cache.Cache.cached):

> `cached(timeout=None, key_prefix='view/%s', unless=None)`
>
> By default the cache key is *view/request.path*. You are able to use this decorator with any function by changing the *key_prefix*. If the token *%s* is located within the *key_prefix* then it will replace that with *request.path*. You are able to use this decorator with any function by changing the *key_prefix*.

and

> `key_prefix` – *[...]* Can optionally be a callable which takes no arguments but returns a string that will be used as the `cache_key`.

So you can set `key_prefix` to a function, and it'll be called (without arguments) to produce the key.

Moreover:

> The returned decorated function now has three function attributes assigned to it. These attributes are readable/writable:
>
> *[...]*
>
> `make_cache_key`
>   A function used in generating the cache_key used.

This function is passed the same arguments the view function is passed. In all, this allows you to produce any cache key you want; either use `key_prefix` and pull out more information from the `request` or `g` or other sources, or assign to `view_function.make_cache_key` and access the same arguments the view function receives.

Then there is the [`@memoize()` decorator](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/#flask.ext.cache.Cache.memoize):

> `memoize(timeout=None, make_name=None, unless=None)`
>
> Use this to cache the result of a function, taking its arguments into account in the cache key.

So this decorator caches return values purely based on the arguments passed into the function. It too supports a `make_cache_key` function.

I've used both decorators to make a Google App Engine Flask project scale to double-digit millions of views per month for a CMS-backed site, storing results in the Google memcached structure. Doing this with Redis would only require setting a configuration option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [cache decorator](https://github.com/dhruvpathak/python-cache-decorator), the cache object you create will have to be a flask cache object instead of django one i.e. should support cache.get and cache.set methods, this is pretty flexible based on how you want to create cache keys, i.e.

- based on what parameters being passed to the method
- in what cases to cache/not cache the result
- Use same cache even if kwarg order is changed, i.e. same cache for my_method(a=1,b=2) and my_method(b=2,a=1) call.

"

```
__author__ = 'Dhruv Pathak'


import cPickle
import logging
import time
from functools import wraps
from django.conf import settings
import traceback

"""following imports are from datautils.py in this repo, datautils
also contains many other useful data utility methods/classes
"""
from datautils import mDict, mList, get_nested_ordered_dict, nested_path_get

"""following import is specific to django framework, and can be altered
based on what type of caching library your code uses"""
from django.core.cache import cache, caches


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def cache_result(cache_key=None, cache_kwarg_keys=None, seconds=900, cache_filter=lambda x: True, cache_setup = "default"):
    def set_cache(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def x(*args, **kwargs):
            if settings.USE_CACHE is not True:
                result = f(*args, **kwargs)
                return result
            try:
                # cache_conn should be a cache object supporting get,set methods
                # can be from python-memcached, pylibmc, django, django-redis-cache, django-redis etc
                cache_conn = caches[cache_setup]
            except Exception, e:
                result = f(*args, **kwargs)
                return result
            final_cache_key = generate_cache_key_for_method(f, kwargs, args, cache_kwarg_keys, cache_key)
            try:
                result = cache_conn.get(final_cache_key)
            except Exception, e:
                result = None
                if settings.DEBUG is True:
                    raise
                else:
                    logger.exception("Cache get failed,k::{0},ex::{1},ex::{2}".format(final_cache_key, str(e), traceback.format_exc()))

            if result is not None and cache_filter(result) is False:
                result = None
                logger.debug("Cache had invalid result:{0},not returned".format(result))

            if result is None: # result not in cache
                result = f(*args, **kwargs)
                if isinstance(result, (mDict, mList)):
                    result.ot = int(time.time())
                if cache_filter(result) is True:
                    try:
                        cache_conn.set(final_cache_key, result, seconds)
                    except Exception, e:
                        if settings.DEBUG is True:
                            raise
                        else:
                            logger.exception("Cache set failed,k::{0},ex::{1},ex::{2},dt::{3}".format(final_cache_key, str(e), traceback.format_exc(), str(result)[0:100],))
                #else:
                #    logger.debug("Result :{0} failed,not cached".format(result))

            else: # result was from cache
                if isinstance(result, (mDict, mList)):
                    result.src = "CACHE_{0}".format(cache_setup)
            return result
        return x
    return set_cache


def generate_cache_key_for_method(method, method_kwargs, method_args, cache_kwarg_keys=None, cache_key=None):
    if cache_key is None:
        if cache_kwarg_keys is not None and len(cache_kwarg_keys) > 0:
            if len(method_args) > 0:
                raise Exception("cache_kwarg_keys mode needs set kwargs,args should be empty")

            method_kwargs = get_nested_ordered_dict(method_kwargs)
            cache_kwarg_values = [nested_path_get(method_kwargs, path_str=kwarg_key, strict=False) for kwarg_key in cache_kwarg_keys]
            if any([kwarg_value is not None for kwarg_value in cache_kwarg_values]) is False:
                raise Exception("all cache kwarg keys values are not set")

            final_cache_key = "{0}::{1}::{2}".format(str(method.__module__), str(method.__name__), hash(cPickle.dumps(cache_kwarg_values)))
        else:
            final_cache_key = "{0}::{1}".format(str(method.__module__), str(method.__name__))
            final_cache_key += "::{0}".format(str(hash(cPickle.dumps(method_args, 0)))) if len(method_args) > 0 else ''
            final_cache_key += "::{0}".format(str(hash(cPickle.dumps(method_kwargs, 0)))) if len(method_kwargs) > 0 else ''
    else:
        final_cache_key = "{0}::{1}::{2}".format(method.__module__, method.__name__, cache_key)

    return final_cache_key
```

2-3 utility methods are imported from this [file](https://github.com/dhruvpathak/misc-python-utils/blob/master/datautils.py) in same repo, you can just put them in same file.